# How to run another exe inside jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to run another `exe` after the unit test execution is also passed in jenkins. I have no idea on how to do this. Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add a build step, probably a Windows Batch File build step.